# How to make connection to the device in wifi via android app..I need persistent connection (That is does not lost after exiting the app)

Tags: android, wifi, android-10.0

Im developing a an android application which is for rooted device.My app is a system app.
In the my app i need to all user to input the router ssid,password so that i need to make connection to the router via wifi.

For this im using requestNetowrk method .(android.net.ConnectivityManager.reqeustNetwor(NetworkRequest,NetworkCallback,Timeout)).

It is connected,But after exiting from app the connection lost.
How to make the connection remains persist after exiting the app.That i am not needed app level connection and needed device level connection.
How to achieve this.

The following are the configurations i used in my app
Android 10 & it is system app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addNetwork(WifiConfiguration config)` from `WifiManager` class.

This API is used for persistent connection in Pre-Android Q version.
From Android Q it is deprecated, but the  deprecation is exempted for Device Owner (DO), Profile Owner (PO) and system apps.

From Android Docs

> int addNetwork(WifiConfiguration config)

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. a) See WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder#build() for new mechanism to trigger connection to a Wi-Fi network. b) See addNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List), removeNetworkSuggestions(java.util.List) for new API to add Wi-Fi networks for consideration when auto-connecting to wifi. Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always fail and return -1.

> **Deprecation Exemptions: Device Owner (DO), Profile Owner (PO) and system apps.**